# pyspark add 0 with empty index

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like below:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|  name  |  index  |  score  |  
+--------+---------+---------+
|  name0 |       0 |      50 |
|  name0 |       2 |      90 |
|  name0 |       3 |     100 |
|  name0 |       5 |      85 |
|  name1 |       1 |      65 |
|  name1 |       2 |      50 |
|  name1 |       3 |      70 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

and index should be 0~5, so what I want to get is:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|  name  |  index  |  score  |  
+--------+---------+---------+
|  name0 |       0 |      50 |
|  name0 |       1 |       0 |
|  name0 |       2 |      90 |
|  name0 |       3 |     100 |
|  name0 |       4 |       0 |
|  name0 |       5 |      85 |
|  name1 |       0 |       0 |
|  name1 |       1 |      65 |
|  name1 |       2 |      50 |
|  name1 |       3 |      70 |
|  name1 |       4 |       0 |
|  name1 |       5 |       0 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

I want to fill 0 in empty index, but I have no idea.
Is there any solution? Please consider that I don't use pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross join the names with a range of indices, then left join to the original dataframe using name and index, and replace nulls with 0.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", True)

df2 = (df.select('name')
         .distinct()
         .join(spark.range(6).toDF('index'))
         .join(df, ['name', 'index'], 'left')
         .fillna({'score': 0})
      )

df2.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
| name|index|score|
+-----+-----+-----+
|name0|    0|   50|
|name0|    1|    0|
|name0|    2|   90|
|name0|    3|  100|
|name0|    4|    0|
|name0|    5|   85|
|name1|    0|    0|
|name1|    1|   65|
|name1|    2|   50|
|name1|    3|   70|
|name1|    4|    0|
|name1|    5|    0|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: actually, I'm using spark 1.6 and it seems there's no crossjoin in this version